# Android: What's next after FingerprintManager onAuthenticationSucceeded?

Tags: android, fingerprint

I am under way adding fingerprint authentication to my application, found lot's of good advice online and managed to successfully implement one of those samples in my app. https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Fingerprint_Authentication_Tutorial

However, the MainActivity of all these examples ends with instantiating a helper class in which the respective callback (onAuthenticationError, onAuthenticationHelp, onAuthenticationSucceeded) functions are defined.

```
// Main activity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
…
FingerprintHandler helper = new FingerprintHandler(this);
            helper.startAuth(fingerprintManager, cryptoObject);
}

…

// Helper class
public class FingerprintHandler extends FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback {
…
   @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(appContext, "Authentication succeeded.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And so does my app now.
However, there is one important bit I haven't found here or in the the blog posts I have been visiting. What's the recommended way to go back to my MainActivity code after the user successfully authenticated?
To handle things such as closing the fingerprint UI and starting the actual application UI with the associated activities.

I can see various ways to do this, e.g.

1. the onAuthenticationSucceeded method could become a launcher for a
   new activity with the code I had in my mainActivity before
2. I somehow redirect the call back methods to be handled inside my
   mainActivity via the implement statement.

But before I refactor my code and try things out I thought I'd ask here for some advice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a way by simply creating a global MainActivity variable and calling MainActivity.InitApplication from onAuthenticationSucceeded.
Not clean but it worked.

But, in the meantime I have also looked into API level 28 BiometricPrompt which is a lot lot simpler.
Took the plunge and upgraded to Androidx and BiometricPrompt and ended up with a much cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

As added security, you should make use of the `CryptoObject` returned on the result from the biometrics callback to encrypt/decrypt the data of your app. Biometrics themselves can be bypassed on a compromised device (fairly easy to do when using root + FRIDA).

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, I need to read up some more on this subject but given that all my data is in an encrypted DB anyway I am not sure there's much value in adding CryptoObject?

Comment: It really depends on how much you want to protect against a compromised device situation. Your encrypted DB will work if all an attacker gets hands on is the DB file itself. However, it is very likely that if that was the case the attacker has root on the device. Therefore could use FRIDA to just bypass your biometrics and access the running app to see the info. It’s easy to do with minor technical skills - just call the success callback method. However, if you use the crypto object its virtually impossible to bypass the biometrics because it wouldn't be able to forge the cryptoObject.